# System.IO.File.Open within netstandard2.0 library from xamarin.forms within UWP fileaccess UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, .net-standard-2.0, file-access

I currently have a handler within my global Xamarin.Forms Mobile App project. This handler contains a System.Io.File.Open on a text file that is located within the Users Document directory.

However, when running the UWP application, it throws the following:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in System.IO.FileSystem.dll 
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users' is denied.
```

I do not have much experience with both Xamarin.Forms and UWP so possibly I am doing something wrong from the start. I did do some research before posting this question, and understood that UWP runs in a sandbox that requires user permission to access directories and/or files within specific locations.

I've heard however that setting the following within `Package.appxmanifest` would allow access to all directories the current user has access to:

```
<rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
```

However that didn't make any difference for me. Then I proceeded and allowed through Windows Settings the application to access the file system as mentioned somewhere. This didn't solve anything either.

Did some more research that UWP has it's own IO interface using IStorageHandlers and related. But these cannot be used within a netstandard2.0 library as far as I've seen.

How would one handle file operations from within a netstandard2.0 library that is included within a UWP application?

Answer (score 2):

The `broadFilesystemAccess` capability will give an application access to all user-accessible files, but only via two mechanisms:

- `Windows.Storage` APIs; or
- `CreateFileFromApp` and similar Win32 APIs.

Since .NET doesn't use either of those APIs under the covers, it can't access locations outside of the app's package / data folders.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is another answer that would suit UWP applications, if there is, please do put them here. However, impatient me that wants to move on decided to uses WPF instead. Luckily Xamarin.Forms also supports WPF and WinForms. For WPF you can follow an official How To here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/wpf .

Luckily for me I was planning on supporting Windows prior to windows 10 so it was a given that I had to switch.